# How can I turn voiceOver off in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, accessibility, voice

I'm trying to turn voice over off for can use our own tts but i couldnt do it yet.
when i open app  voice over also talks before my tts, i wanna voice over stay silence.
 Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a good idea. VoiceOver is not just about the voice reading the text but a lot of gestures, traits and other behaviors. Unless you mimic them all perfectly your users would probably be more upset with the functionality than happy for another voice.